# VB 2010 Express connected to database microsoft access 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim sqlquery As String = "INSERT INTO Table1(Customer Name,Address,Contact Number,Type Of Customer)VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "')"

        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand

        With sqlcommand
            .CommandText = sqlquery
            .Connection = con
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MsgBox("ONE RECORD SUCCESFULLY ADDED :)")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Can somebody help me? It says that there is an error in INSERT INTO statement, i dont know why. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting [] around column names that contain a space.

( [Customer Name], Address, [Contact Number], [Type Of Customer] )

Answer (score 0):

It is important to enclose your field in [your field] when they have spaces in them, else it considers it as two fields and search for separator which there is none in this case.

hopes my answers helps a little.